# Matching 1 word from a sentences

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, matching, strpos

how can i search for 1 or 2 word match?

```
<?php
$a = key1, key2, key3;
$b = key3, key4, key5;

if (strpos($a,$b) != false) {
    echo 'Great Is Found';
}
?>
```

this "strpos" returns result only if all sentence it's the same, what if I want even only 1 or 2 words match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `array_intersect`, `array_map` and `explode`

```
$a = "key1, key2, key3";
$b = "key3, key4, key5";

$intersect = array_intersect(array_map('trim',explode(",",$a)), array_map('trim',explode(",",$b)));

if ($intersect) {
    echo 'Great Is Found';
    var_dump($intersect);
}
```

Comment: thanx for the great and quick help, if i want to put this code in "foreach" how i can do it?

Comment: @user2568578 It's easy. But you should let me know about your data format. Foreach what?

Answer (score 0):

After quick read it seems that you are looking for [`similar_text`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) or [`levenshtein`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) methods.